# How does c# type safety affect the garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, type-safety

I'm dealing with code that handles large buffers (> 100MB) and manipulation of these is done in `unsafe` blocks. I'd like to refactor these to avoid `unsafe` code. I'm wondering about the likely memory performance gains (positive/negative/neutral) before I embark on that.

I assert that if the compiler can verify types, it could possibly generate better code and that could also mean good GC performance. Is this a valid assertion? What is your experience? Thanks.

Comment: Of more relevance than *type safety* is your pinning activities in the `unsafe` blocks.

Comment: Yes, buffers are pinned in 'fixed' blocks before various manipulations, which I believe an outcome of letting go of type-safety in order to manipulate with pointers.

Comment: Pinning doesn't make any difference.  These large arrays are allocated in the LOH, they are not movable.

Comment: @Hans Passant: That's a good point; I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your buffers are (used for).

Such large buffers will be placed on the Large Object heap (LOH) so be sure to read up on that for the consequences.

At best, i would expect equal performance.

Answer (score 1):

`unsafe` blocks are a language feature, not a CLR feature. So they don't really exist at run time. What *does* exist at run time is pinned variables, and if you can avoid those, you *might* get a performance gain, but that depends on the tradeoff between the costs/benefits. So don't worry about performance impacts unless the code pins a 100 MB buffer into memory for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I expect **negative** influence. Besides the disappearance of the 'safe' flag, I cannot see any advantages of removing the unsafe code:

1. replacing the pointer access to the
   arrays (I suppose you are using
   those?) with regular array indices will introduce an array
   length check **-> less performance**. Also, in most situations, pointer arrithmetic - even if it is not as fast as known from native languages - will be the fastest method to access your data (arrays).
2. The compiler does "know" the types
   anyway - even in unsafe blocks. I
   wouldn't see any chance for it to
   make 'better' code. Also, even
   'better' code would only influence
   the GC performance, if it would lead
   to less objects being created. I
   doubt, the compiler can avoid the
   creation of new objects - just by
   knowing the type for them. **-> no
   improvement either**.
3. The arguments about pinning have
   been stated above already. Getting
   rid of pinned objects might improve
   the performance a little - but only
   for small objects. Not for large
   objects which live on the (non
   compacting) large object heap, since
   they will not be moved anyway. **-> neutral**